# When to stop training in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, training-data

I am using bvlc_reference_caffenet for training. I am doing both training and testing. Below is an example log of my trained network:

```
I0430 11:49:08.408740 23343 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0430 11:49:21.221074 23343 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0430 11:49:34.038710 23343 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0430 11:49:46.816813 23343 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0430 11:49:56.630870 23334 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.932502
I0430 11:49:56.630940 23334 solver.cpp:397]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.388662 (* 1 = 0.388662 loss)
I0430 11:49:57.218236 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71000 (0.319361 iter/s, 62.625s/20 iters), loss = 0.00146191
I0430 11:49:57.218300 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00146191 (* 1 = 0.00146191 loss)
I0430 11:49:57.218308 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71000, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:50:09.168726 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71020 (1.67357 iter/s, 11.9505s/20 iters), loss = 0.000806865
I0430 11:50:09.168778 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.000806868 (* 1 = 0.000806868 loss)
I0430 11:50:09.168787 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71020, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:50:21.127496 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71040 (1.67241 iter/s, 11.9588s/20 iters), loss = 0.000182312
I0430 11:50:21.127539 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.000182314 (* 1 = 0.000182314 loss)
I0430 11:50:21.127562 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71040, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:50:33.248086 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71060 (1.65009 iter/s, 12.1206s/20 iters), loss = 0.000428604
I0430 11:50:33.248260 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.000428607 (* 1 = 0.000428607 loss)
I0430 11:50:33.248272 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71060, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:50:45.518955 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71080 (1.62989 iter/s, 12.2707s/20 iters), loss = 0.00108446
I0430 11:50:45.519006 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00108447 (* 1 = 0.00108447 loss)
I0430 11:50:45.519011 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71080, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:50:51.287315 23341 data_layer.cpp:73] Restarting data prefetching from start.
I0430 11:50:57.851781 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71100 (1.62169 iter/s, 12.3328s/20 iters), loss = 0.00150949
I0430 11:50:57.851828 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0015095 (* 1 = 0.0015095 loss)
I0430 11:50:57.851837 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71100, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:51:09.912184 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71120 (1.65832 iter/s, 12.0604s/20 iters), loss = 0.00239335
I0430 11:51:09.912330 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00239335 (* 1 = 0.00239335 loss)
I0430 11:51:09.912340 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71120, lr = 0.001
I0430 11:51:21.968586 23334 solver.cpp:218] Iteration 71140 (1.65888 iter/s, 12.0563s/20 iters), loss = 0.00161807
I0430 11:51:21.968646 23334 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.00161808 (* 1 = 0.00161808 loss)
I0430 11:51:21.968654 23334 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 71140, lr = 0.001
```

What confuses me is the loss. I was going to stop training my network when loss goes below 0.0001 but there are two losses: training loss and test loss. Training loss seems to stay around 0.0001 but test loss is at 0.388 which is way above the threshold I set. Which one do I use to stop my training?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having such a large gap between test and train performance might indicate that you [over-fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) your data.
The purpose of validation set is to make sure you do not overfit. You should use the performance on the validation set to decide whether to stop training or precede.

Comment: Also, when you say validation, do you mean the test loss shown in the log? Validation is actually different from test but in the context of the log shown above, I think test loss is treated as validation loss.

Comment: @MoneyBall in many cases the TEST phase in caffe is indeed the validation

Comment: @MoneyBall ideally they should be the same.

Comment: For AlexNet, there is one loss for test and one loss for training so I can keep track of the differences. What about GoogleNet where there are three different losses for training? Which one should I use to decide when to stop training?

Comment: @MoneyBall in GoogLeNet you may overfit different parts of the model...

Comment: @ Shai Hmm I see. I only set lr_mult=1 on three fc layers but it doesn't seem to work so well. Do you have any advice on how to go about training on GoogLeNet? Would SVD trick work as well in GoogLeNet?

Comment: GoogLeNet uses loss1 and loss2 only to push gradients deeper into the net. At test time one usually only uses the topmost prediction and ignoring the two "side branches" of loss1 and loss1. If you only finetune you can discard these branches completely and set `lr_mult: 1` for the top most layers of loss3 branch.

Comment: @ Shai Ah I see. If I set `lr_mult:1` on other side branches, will it overfit?

Comment: @MoneyBall it will have no effect: if you only change the classifier layer but not allowing the underlying features to change, and you do not use this classifier eventually then you are doing nothing...

Comment: @ Shai I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to stop training when your validation accuracy hits a plateau.  Your data above indicates that you have, indeed, over-trained your model.

Ideally, the training, testing, and validation error should be roughly equal.  In practice, this rarely happens.

Note that the loss is *not* a good metric, unless your loss function and weights are the same for all phases of evaluation.  For instance, GoogleNet weights the training loss function across three layers, but the validation test worries only about final accuracy.

Comment: That depends on your data and your final application.  You have to determine your goals and objectives, and then tune your training regimen toward those goals.  The most general metric is the one I gave you in the first sentence of my answer: when the validation accuracy plateaus.