# Selecting training and validation sets for convolutional neural network has a big impact on test accuracy

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I am doing traffic sign recognition work using German Traffic Sign Detection Benchmark database.  This has 43 classes, with at least 400 images in each class.  Images may have up to 3 traffic signs.

When I have randomly selected images for training and validation set I get a huge difference in network's test accuracy. I constructed two data sets: one has 75% training images and 25% validation images; the other has 70% training images and 30% validation images.

I am using GoogLeNet with identical hyper-parameters for training, including 30 epochs.

After training, I test with a different set of images that are designed for testing.  With the first data set, I get almost 10% lower accuracy than with the second one.  Could some one explain this?

Could it be that it randomly selected "easier" images for training and that is why I am getting lower results?

P.S. for both of the data sets I am using the same images, just dividing it differently by percentages.

Link to data set: http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset

Comment: 10 percent, or 10 percent point? Have you tried both data sets multiple times, or only once?

Comment: Please rephrase your question: it's difficult to understand your settings and result.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you train and validate using a random split of one dataset and the test using a **different** set of images?

Comment: On both times the test set was the same, it is just a different set then the training set. Training set was divided into two parts one for training and the other one for validation. I have tested both of them several times. And always I get that the one with more images in training set gets a lower result.

Comment: sounds like [overfitting.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43703584/1714410)

Comment: Hmm forgot to think about it, it must be that, Thanks.

Comment: Have you stratified your data set?

Comment: Yes I have stratified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many classes of signs do you have?  Is GoogLeNet known to work well on this data set?  Remember, GoogLeNet was designed specifically to perform well on the ILSVRC 2012 data set: almost 1.3M training images, 1000 classes.  It broadens to several hundred parallel kernels, giving it a lot of flexibility for the problem.

If you have a significantly smaller problem -- say, 900 images in a handful of categories -- then GoogLeNet's magnitude will likely over-fit your application quite easily.  For instance, note that the final fully-connected layer of 1000 parameters is more than needed to *individually recognize every image in the training set*.  The intermediate layers of 128-200+ filters are going to find a variety of spurious features, such as the pattern of greenery around six of the speed zone signs.

Also, remember that GoogLeNet was built to identify a single figure within the input image: the Traffic Sign data base may have up to 6 signs in an image.  This can also confound your training, depending on how you classify multi-sign images.

If you feel you need the GoogLeNet complexity for this task, I suggest that you reduce the widths of the layers.  For instance, where ILSVRC history suggests that your model learn to identify facial features, vehicle parts, and flower petals, road signs are far more restricted in their visual elements.  Thus, although you may want the first layer (edge and region detection) to remain full-bodied, you won't need so many filters in the intermediate layers.

No, I can't give you a reliable starting point: I haven't done the months of experiments necessary to tune the model to the problem.  If you want to see an extreme example, train GoogLeNet for the recommended number of iterations, but feed it the MNIST data base.  Better yet, give it text-processor screen shots of tic-tac-toe positions, classified only as "win", "draw", and "lose".

Comment: I was just wondering why it gave me this big difference. I am using  German Traffic Sign Detection Benchmark database which has 43 classes where in each class there is at least 400 images, some of the classes have more then 3000 images. Also in an image there is only traffic sign and a bit of background. With the second data set (the 70% for training) I am getting quit high results top 1 accuracy 95.10% after 30 epochs, without augmentation or anything else and with the bigger one (75% for training) its 87.55% top 1. I am guessing that it might be because of overfitting as @shai mentioned.

Comment: Thanks; you might include a link to the data base; the supposedly official one I found has only 900 images -- obviously not the same one.

Comment: I merely elaborated on the basic point of over-fitting.  You set a 1000-class design to handle a 43-class problem.  You found a point where the slope of the change in accuracy got quite steep.